# Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found CodeIgniter 2.2.0

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi developers, 
              I wants print "HelloWorld" in **codeigniter**.

```
<?php

Class Helloworld extends Controller {

    public function Helloworld()
    {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function hello() 
    {
        $this->load->view('helloworld');
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you save this code? Did you save this code in `CI/application/controllers`? Did you configure your base_url properly inside `CI/application/config/config.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using the following:

```
Class Helloworld extends CI_Controller {
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your code like this

Change

Controller to CI_Controller

And

Parent::controller () to parent::__construct ()